# How do I run a VM within a VM with separate IPs accessible on a local network?

Tags: networking, security, virtual-machine, vmware, exploit

First off, I know my question sounds confusing.

**Brief background information**: I am an instructor for a network security penetration test course. I help create scenarios with complex networks via virtual machines. Which my students must attempt to gain access to, all while minimizing their presence within a network.

The intent is for a student to see that there is an Administrator currently logged on which should prompt them to immediately get off before they are caught.

To do this, my goal here is to automate Administrative activity on a machine without a process showing up in the system process list that indicates this is occurring. I want it to "appear" legit.

The only way I've really been able to find out how to hide a process from a system process list would be using very sketchy rootkits that I'd rather not deal with.  Unless someone has a solution they would recommend, I'd love to hear your suggestions.

However, I have come up with another potential solution.

My plan is to run the VM that they will access within another VM.  I will then use a Autohotkey script on the first VM that will control the mouse and keyboard and simulate these Administrative activities that will kick off shortly after a student gets onto the system.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to configure the network adapters so that the second VM is accessible from another machine on the physical network.  I want to make the first VM "transparent" to them.  I'm not too concerned from hiding the first VM's presence from the network, so I don't care if it shows up in a nmap scan or something.

I just want to be able to access a VM within a VM from another box on the same physical network.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you successfully run a VM inside of a VM yet? The usual problem is that processors only handle one level of visualization, causing the second layer VM to simply refuse to start because the visualization extensions are unavailable inside of the first VM, or go with a fully-emulated CPU, which is significantly and noticeably slower.

Comment: "However, I am having trouble figuring out how to configure the network adapters so that the second VM is accessible from another machine on the physical network" - This doesn't give us nearly enough detail for which to provide an answer. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: What networking modes are you using?  I think bridging all network adapters should give you the desired result.

Comment: Why does the VM need to be inside a VM?  Put both on the host, and just manage the one VM from the other using the Vmware Powerhshell CLI commands.

Comment: +1 for DarthAndroid, except he means *virtualization*, not visualization. But he is right.

Comment: @Darth Android So yes, I have successfully ran a VM withing another VM using VM Player.  I even successfully ran the Auto Hotkey script on the first VM which performed typical Administrative functions on the second VM which did not show up in the process list of the second VM.  So that part I know I can do, and it works.  However I'm currently doing it on my laptop, not the ESX server.  My first VM only has 3GB of RAM and the second one is using 1GB of that RAM.  I also assigned the first one 2 processors, then gave the second one 1 of those processors.  It runs slow, but it runs.

Comment: @joeqwerty Ok so I have the first VM with IP address 192.168.162.1, the VM inside of it has IP address 192.168.162.2. Both have been statically assigned. I also regenerated the MAC addresses so that they are different since the 2nd VM was a clone of the first. On my physical Host machine I statically assigned IP address 192.168.162.3.  What I want to be able to do is ping 192.168.162.2 from 192.168.162.3.  However there is no response.

Comment: @heavyd  Both VM's are in Bridged Mode with "Replicate physical network connection" checked.

Comment: @Zoredache I need to replicate Administrator activity on the second VM via the GUI, not command line.  There also can be no processes running or network connections established to the machine in order to accomplish this.  It needs to appear to be a standalone box where a Administrator physically logs on and starts performing random administrative activities via the GUI.  Does this make sense?